# Upload fuerte package problem

Tags: ros, rosdistro

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi!
I make a package on ROS Fuerte and want to upload the package on ROS Wiki.
I follow steps in tutorial until the step "Verify your changes before commiting the changes". How can I do that with ros fuerte? I can not find out the distribution.yaml file

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/224068/upload-fuerte-package-problem/) by [tn0432](https://answers.ros.org/users/21276/tn0432/) on ROS Answers with karma: 60 on 2016-01-13

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2016-01-13**:
Please provide a link to the tutorial that you're follow. Also note that Fuerte is no longer support, so while you can create a wiki page, there is no longer hosting for auto-generated documentation.

**Comment by [tn0432](https://answers.ros.org/users/21276/tn0432/) on 2016-01-14**:
Sorry! Here is the link: http://wiki.ros.org/rosdistro/Tutorials/Indexing%20Your%20ROS%20Repository%20for%20Documentation%20Generation

Actually, I have made a ROS fuerte package. I am trying to upload to ROS wiki. Is the link the best way to follow? Thanks! I very appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

ROS Fuerte has been unsupported for several years, and the wiki indexing no longer supports it. (Note that the page you've referenced says the instructions are for "Groovy and later").

You can manually create a wiki page, but it will not have the automatically generated header.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2016-01-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tn0432](https://answers.ros.org/users/21276/tn0432/) on 2016-01-18**:
Hello! I have uploaded my project with Indigo to github and made a pull request. Do you know when document job is scheduled in order to do wiki indexing? Thanks

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2016-01-18**:
As the tutorial says, you should be able to search the [ROS build server](http://jenkins.ros.org/) to find your documentation job, and that should show you the job information. It may take up to 24 hours between when you submit the pull request and when your doc job is created.

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2016-01-18**:
If this was your pull request, it was rejected: https://github.com/ros/rosdistro/pull/10289 . You need to submit an updated pull request for indigo.

**Comment by [tn0432](https://answers.ros.org/users/21276/tn0432/) on 2016-01-19**:
hi! Not that one. I put in indigo 4 days ago https://github.com/tn0432/rosdistro/commit/16c001b7dd86b40b41d0c2605e238722d6db14bd , but still not find out in ROS build server. Let I try again! hope it work